# Who are some 19th century philosophers to posit something akin to meaning holism and how did they argue in favor of it?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

According to [this](https://philosophy.ceu.edu/events/2018-11-21/holism-vs-particularism-evidential-debate) Whewell debated with Stuart Mill on "Holism vs. Particularism".

What were their arguments in support of the 'meaning holism' if they had any?

Comment: It's chapter 4 in Achinstein's book [Speculation: Within and About Science](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780190615055.001.0001/oso-9780190615055-chapter-4).

Comment: @Conifold Pleasee if you have access to it present some of the arguments here

Comment: Sorry, I do not.

Comment: You can get some idea from [Forster, The Debate between Whewell and Mill](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237432830_The_Debate_between_Whewell_and_Mill_on_the_Nature_of_Scientific_Induction), registration on ResearchGate is free.